# Find a direction $\mathbf v$ in which $D_vf(0,0)$ exists.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let
>   $$f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if }x=y \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Find a direction $\mathbf v$ in which $D_vf(0,0)$ exists.

My working:

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} f_x(x,y) = \frac{f(x + h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}$

$=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+h, 0) - f(0,0)}{h}$

$= \frac{0 - 1}{h}$

$= -\infty$

Apart from this, I have no idea how to approach this question. I would appreciate it if someone can post a solution and **their reasoning behind each step**. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw this out, you see that the curve has the value one along the line $x=y$. Intuitively, the derivative should make sense if we move strictly along that line, and the derivative should be zero.

Indeed, letting $v=\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\rangle$, (we need a unit vector), we have $x=y$ and the derivative will be

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0+h)-f(0,0)}{|\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt2}h,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}h\rangle|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-1}{h}=0.$$